# Use of custom authorization decorator in django vs in view function call

Tags: python, django, view

I have a view where I want to verify the permission of a user to edit / delete a post. It should check if the user making the request is the user who created the post.

Below is my view with a few different ways of solving this problem, I wrote a class based view with a mixin, a decorator, and a general purpose function.

I'm confused as to which would be the best practice. On one hand I feel that a class based view is overkill for this and will ultimately make the code less clear, I also don't like that the decorator will make 3 function calls as opposed to the one call I can make with the check_function.

It should be noted I plan to use this solution on other models with similar structure.

Any help and advice is appreciated, thanks!

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

'''
def verify_author(func):
    def check_and_call(request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = kwargs["id"]
        instance = get_object_or_404(model, id=id)
        if request.user == instance.author:
            return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied
    return check_and_call
'''
def check_author(request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    if not request.user == instance.author:
        raise PermissionDenied

'''

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView

class IsAuthorMixin(object):
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(IsAuthorMixin, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
        if not instance.author == self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied # 403, might be changed to 404
        return instance

class PostUpdateView(IsAuthorMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'Post_form.html'

class JobDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, IsAuthorMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

'''


@login_required
@verify_author
def post_update(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    check_author(request, instance=instance)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance) 

    if form.is_valid():
        instance= form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_abs_url())

    context = {"form": form,}
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)


@login_required
@verify_author
def post_destroy(request, id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    check_author(request, instance=instance)
    instance.delete()
    return redirect("posts:list")
```